# Is it legal for me to ride a bicycle on the pavement (sidewalk)?

Tags: uk, legal

UK only, just wanted to check if it's actually legal. The area I'm living on is deadly on the roads, so want to know about riding on pavements (sidewalk/pedestrian walkways) instead where there is no bike lane (half of the roads have bike lanes around here and suddenly they disappear...).

Comment: Just as a references, The question is specific to the UK, but...
Totally acceptable in the states.
As a matter of fact, bicyclists are to be treated just like another vehicle on the road, held to the same traffic laws as a car.

Comment: Same here in Canada.

Comment: "Pavement" in this case means the sidewalk, *not* the road. You should update your answer, as it's currently incorrect. It is generally unacceptable most places in the 'States (and here in Toronto, Canada) to ride on the sidewalk.

Comment: As a pretty important side note, "pavement" in this case refers to the sidewalk, *not* a paved road.

Comment: Also check here: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/6255/can-cyclists-legally-ride-on-the-sidewalk/6269#6269

Comment: Out of curiosity, what roads do you consider deadly? Anything that has 50km/h or below speed limit should be OK to cycle.

Comment: @ Mladen Jablanović: Obviously you do not live in my country..... More cyclists die on 50km/h limit roads than open roads (100km/h) where I live.

Comment: A bit late, but don't we call it a "footpath" ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [the Highway Code](http://www.direct.gov.uk/en/TravelAndTransport/Highwaycode/DG_069837):

> **Rule 64**
>
> You MUST NOT cycle on a pavement.

So the short answer is a definite no, although discretion is given for young children riding on the pavement.

[This article](http://www.bikehub.co.uk/featured-articles/cycling-and-the-law/) has details the rules for cycling on things like footways, footpaths and bridlepaths.  (In short: no, no and yes - but the article is probably worth a read.)

More information about rules in other countries can be found [in this question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/6255/can-cyclists-legally-ride-on-the-sidewalk).

Comment: As you mentioned children: Here in Germany there's an conflict of law - children may not use the road but have tu se the pacement. Adults may not use the pavement and have to use the road. By law parents are also required to look after the children. In the end there's no good way to deal with this in a legal way and many parents ride on the pavement, too ...