# Inline trailers

Tags: trailer, children

Anyone know of a bike trailer that is narrow (like a [BOB Yak](http://www.bobgear.com/yak)) for kids? We have a co-pilot trailer, but the width is pretty wide, often maxing out a sidewalk making it hard to pass or be passed.

We have twin 4 year old boys and need an easier way to get them to and from school. Its a bit too far for them to ride on their own yet.

Comment: Aren't bicycles classified as vehicles in your area, and are, hence, obligated to use the road? If so, then a bike lane is a bit wider than a sidewalk.

Comment: Yes. Legally. That doesnt mean my wife is willing to ride in the road pulling a trailer where motorists could care less about a bike lane.

Comment: Riding on the sidewalk can bring a false sense of security. I hope she's being careful at driveways and intersections, [the most dangerous locations](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/6257/8) for those who ride a bike on the sidewalk. If it's an option, perhaps she simply needs to find a safer route?

Comment: agreed. She has a pretty low key route. Don't want to banter about routes or laws. Just wondering if there is a trailer that offers inline seating.

Comment: Fair enough, we're just chatting in the comments here. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on how comfortable your kids are on a bike, you could get something like the [Trail-a-Bike Tandem](http://www.trail-a-bike.com/products/trail-a-bikes/folder-tandem/)  It's as narrow as a regular bike.  I don't have any experience with it, but it seems like it might work.

[Xtracycle](http://www.xtracycle.com/) also have various [bolt on longtail attachments](http://www.xtracycle.com/cargo-bicycles/xtracycle-cargo-bicycles/xtracycle-freeradical.html/) for regular bikes. I'm not sure if two four year olds would be too heavy on a longtail, but it could be an option. [this guy](http://www.jpbikeresearch.com/2009/10/riding-with-my-kids/) seems to do it.  Wouldn't be something you'd want to take on and off all the time like a trailer, but if you aren't doing any serious tours you could ride around on it without the kids.

Comment: while not a trailer, I love the tandem trail a bike. I have never seen one like that. Moving to the top of my list indeed. Great find!

Comment: I had a single trail a bike. When the kid throws his weight from side to side it can be quite unsettling. With two on the back, I imagine stability would become quite an issue.